# Trying to update text file records in place and write them out to an output file

Tags: python, file, text

I read an input file and try to reformat the date field where it is not fully formed by replacing single digit 'day' values in the date with two digit 'day' values. Appeared to work well at first then I noticed that the input file had (279) records but the output was written with (615) records. Many, if not all, of the single digit day values were replaced as expected but the original versions of those records seemed to have been written out as well to the output. Of course the expectation was that the output would have (239) records as well ??? (The script runs without throwing any errors).

```
replacements = {'/1':'/01', '9/':'09/', '7/':'07/'}
file2 = open(r"c:\users\liddvdp\desktop\IBC CAP OUT.txt", "w")
with open(r"c:\users\liddvdp\desktop\IBC CAP.txt", "r") as reader:
         for line in reader:
             for src, target in replacements.items():
                 line = line.replace(src, target)
                 file2.write(line)
```

Comment: suggest to add some example of the data

Answer (score 0):

You should write:

```
replacements = {'/1':'/01', '9/':'09/', '7/':'07/'}
file2 = open(r"c:\users\liddvdp\desktop\IBC CAP OUT.txt", "w")
with open(r"c:\users\liddvdp\desktop\IBC CAP.txt", "r") as reader:
    for line in reader:
        for src, target in replacements.items():
            line = line.replace(src, target)
        file2.write(line)
```

Otherwhise you edit each line three times, and write it three times in the output file.

Comment: I am unable to detect the difference between the suggested fix and the original version ??

Comment: The last row "files.write(line)" shouldn't be in the inner for loop. It should be in the outer for loop. When the row is in the inner for loop, it write the same line multiple times in the output file.

Comment: I  see the point of this now. I changed the indentation so that the write would be in the outer loop and got much improved results, the date 'value strings' are all good....but the strangest thing, the input file has (239) records the output only wrote (205) even though they look good.

Comment: So-o-o for some reason the whole loop to read the input file stopped at record 205 and no more records were processed, the last  34 not handled.

Comment: I would include the input file since it's small but really see a way to do that .........